# Using bash script for downloading data

Tags: bash, scripts, websites, download-manager

I am a beginner at programming. I am trying to do a stock analysis and want to download historical data from www.moneycontrol.com website. Please see below the webpage:

> https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/histstock.php?ex=N&sc_id=TIS&mycomp=Tata%20Steel

On this webpage, I want to select "Exchange" as NSE, Select Company name as "Tata Steel" and select dates as "From 01-01-2000" to "02-05-2019" and press Go.
As expected, this is a huge data and is split over many pages.

Furthermore, this is data for only 1 scrip and I want to download the data for many scrips.

Is it possible to download this huge data in a single file by using a bash or python scripting and using wget or curl?

Comment: Why don't you download the data you need from NSE or BSE websites? I'm not sure moneycontrol is the best source for what you want.

Comment: I was able to download data from NSE website using wget command loop.
 However, in this case the data is actual Trading Price data i.e. it does not account for bonus issues. For eg, there was a split in RELIANCE stock on the 6th of September. So price data for reliance shows as follows:
6th September Open price = 1626.4 
7th September Open price = 823
Moneycontrol data has been adjusted for this split